# Climbed on/climbed over the sidewalk

Tags: word-usage, american-english

A person who was just learning to drive, by mistake climbed on the sidewalk a bit.  (The car gets inclined as the two tyres on one side climb the sidewalk.)

So what would be used:

> I climbed over the sidewalk.
>
> I climbed the sidewalk.

So should it be "climb" or "climb over"? If not, what is a better alternative?

Should it be "**I got the wheels on the sidewalk by mistake**"?

Answer (score 2):

You can  simply say:

> I accidentally drove on the sidewalk.

Compare the following extract:

> California Vehicle Code 21663 prohibits motorists ***from driving on sidewalks***. The only exception is that a ***motorist may drive on a sidewalk*** while he enters or leaves a property.

Answer (score 1):

The typical expression in British usage is "to mount the kerb"  (US spelling would be "curb") ([example](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/mount-the-curb.3229118/)). The kerb is the edge of the pavement (US sidewalk) and it seems likely that the learner would only go onto the kerb.

"Climbed the sidewalk" would be acceptable, but "climbed over" would be odd as it suggests going over the sidewalk and down the other side. It might be easier to say "I accidentally drove on the kerb"

Answer (score 1):

A driver who is learning to drive might **drive up over the curb** (kerb) or **drive up onto the sidewalk**. Or as James K said: mount the curb [kerb].

The word climb here is really a no-go except as a metaphor, but not an accurate description as you might see in an accident report.

The phrasal verbs here would be: drive up over curb (kerb) or drive up onto the sidewalk.